# Given a filesystem path, is there a shorter way to extract the filename without its extension?

Tags: c#, path, filenames, file-extension, path-manipulation

I program in WPF C#.  I have e.g. the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\hello.txt
```

and I want to extract **`hello`** from it.

The path is a `string` retrieved from a database.  Currently I'm using the following code to split the path by `'\'` and then split again by `'.'`:

```cs
string path = "C:\\Program Files\\hello.txt";
string[] pathArr = path.Split('\\');
string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('.');
string fileName = fileArr.Last().ToString();
```

It works, but I believe there should be shorter and smarter solution to that. Any idea?

Comment: In my system, `Path.GetFileName("C:\\dev\\some\\path\\to\\file.cs")` is returning the same string and not converting it to "file.cs" for some reason. If I copy/paste my code into an online compiler (like http://rextester.com/), it works...?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

[`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename)

> Returns the file name and extension of a file path that is represented
> by a read-only character span.

---

[`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension)

> Returns the file name without the extension of a file path that is
> represented by a read-only character span.

---

The [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path) class is wonderful.

Answer (score 104):

try

```
fileName = Path.GetFileName (path);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Answer (score 36):

try

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

demo

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileNameWithoutExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following:
//
// GetFileNameWithoutExtension('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile'
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: It seems Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() is not working with a file extension > 3 characters.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) API as follow:

```
 var filenNme = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension([File Path]);
```

More info: [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Answer (score 20):

```
var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\Program Files\hello.txt");
```

This will return "hello" for fileName.

Answer (score 11):

```
string Location = "C:\\Program Files\\hello.txt";

string FileName = Location.Substring(Location.LastIndexOf('\\') +
    1);
```

Comment: +1 since this might be Helpful in the case wherein this works as a Backup wherein the file name contains invalid characters [ <, > etc in Path.GetInvalidChars()].

Comment: This is actually quite useful when working with path on UNIX ftp servers.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, the code in the question does not produce the described output.  It extracts the file **extension** (`"txt"`) and not the file **base name** (`"hello"`).  To do that the last line should call `First()`, not `Last()`, like this...

```cs
static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit(string path)
{
    string[] pathArr = path.Split('\\');
    string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('.');
    string fileBaseName = fileArr.First().ToString();

    return fileBaseName;
}
```

Having made that change, one thing to think about as far as improving this code is the amount of garbage it creates:

- A `string[]` containing one `string` for each path segment in `path`
- A `string[]` containing at least one `string` for each `.` in the last path segment in `path`

Therefore, extracting the base file name from the sample path `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"` should produce the (temporary) `object`s `"C:"`, `"Program Files"`, `"hello.txt"`, `"hello"`, `"txt"`, a `string[3]`, and a `string[2]`.  This could be significant if the method is called on a large number of paths.  To improve this, we can search `path` ourselves to locate the start and end points of the base name and use those to create *one* new `string`...

```cs
static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe(string path)
{
    // Fails on paths with no file extension - DO NOT USE!!
    int startIndex = path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    int endIndex = path.IndexOf('.', startIndex);
    string fileBaseName = path.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

    return fileBaseName;
}
```

This is using the index of the character after the last `\` as the start of the base name, and from there looking for the first `.` to use as the index of the character after the end of the base name.  Is this shorter than the original code?  Not quite.  Is it a "smarter" solution?  I think so.  At least, it would be if not for the fact that...

As you can see from the comment, the previous method is problematic.  Though it works if you assume all paths end with a file name with an extension, it will throw an exception if the path ends with `\` (i.e. a directory path) or otherwise contains no extension in the last segment.  To fix this, we need to add an extra check to account for when `endIndex` is `-1` (i.e. `.` is not found)...

```cs
static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring(string path)
{
    int startIndex = path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    int endIndex = path.IndexOf('.', startIndex);
    int length = (endIndex >= 0 ? endIndex : path.Length) - startIndex;
    string fileBaseName = path.Substring(startIndex, length);

    return fileBaseName;
}
```

Now this version is nowhere near shorter than the original, but it is more efficient and (now) correct, too.

As far as .NET methods that implement this functionality, many other answers suggest using [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension), which is an obvious, easy solution but **does not produce the same results** as the code in the question.  There is a subtle but important difference between `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` (`GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` below): the former extracts everything before the *first* `.` and the latter extracts everything before the *last* `.`.  This doesn't make a difference for the sample `path` in the question, but take a look at this table comparing the results of the above four methods when called with various paths...

| Description | Method | Path | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Single extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Single extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Single extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Double extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt.ext"` | `"hello"` |
| Double extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt.ext"` | `"hello.txt"` |
| Double extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt.ext"` | `"hello"` |
| Double extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt.ext"` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello"` | `"hello"` |
| No extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello"` | `"hello"` |
| No extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello"` | **EXCEPTION: Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')** |
| No extension | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello"` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leading period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\.hello.txt"` | `""` |
| Leading period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\.hello.txt"` | `".hello"` |
| Leading period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\.hello.txt"` | `""` |
| Leading period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\.hello.txt"` | `""` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trailing period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt."` | `"hello"` |
| Trailing period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt."` | `"hello.txt"` |
| Trailing period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt."` | `"hello"` |
| Trailing period | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\hello.txt."` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"C:\Program Files\"` | `""` |
| Directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"C:\Program Files\"` | `""` |
| Directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"C:\Program Files\"` | **EXCEPTION: Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')** |
| Directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"C:\Program Files\"` | `""` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Current file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Current file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Current file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Current file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parent file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `"..\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Parent file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `"..\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Parent file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `"..\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| Parent file path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `"..\hello.txt"` | `"hello"` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parent directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit()` | `".."` | `""` |
| Parent directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingPath()` | `".."` | `"."` |
| Parent directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe()` | `".."` | `""` |
| Parent directory path | `GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring()` | `".."` | `""` |

...and you'll see that `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` yields different results when passed a path where the file name has a double extension or a leading and/or trailing `.`.  You can try it for yourself with the following code...

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO6921105
{
    internal class PathExtractionResult
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSplit(string path)
        {
            string[] pathArr = path.Split('\\');
            string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('.');
            string fileBaseName = fileArr.First().ToString();

            return fileBaseName;
        }

        private static string GetFileBaseNameUsingPath(string path)
        {
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        }

        private static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstringUnsafe(string path)
        {
            // Fails on paths with no file extension - DO NOT USE!!
            int startIndex = path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
            int endIndex = path.IndexOf('.', startIndex);
            string fileBaseName = path.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

            return fileBaseName;
        }

        private static string GetFileBaseNameUsingSubstring(string path)
        {
            int startIndex = path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
            int endIndex = path.IndexOf('.', startIndex);
            int length = (endIndex >= 0 ? endIndex : path.Length) - startIndex;
            string fileBaseName = path.Substring(startIndex, length);

            return fileBaseName;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            MethodInfo[] testMethods = typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                .Where(method => method.Name.StartsWith("GetFileBaseName"))
                .ToArray();
            var inputs = new[] {
                new { Description = "Single extension",      Path = @"C:\Program Files\hello.txt"     },
                new { Description = "Double extension",      Path = @"C:\Program Files\hello.txt.ext" },
                new { Description = "No extension",          Path = @"C:\Program Files\hello"         },
                new { Description = "Leading period",        Path = @"C:\Program Files\.hello.txt"    },
                new { Description = "Trailing period",       Path = @"C:\Program Files\hello.txt."    },
                new { Description = "Directory path",        Path = @"C:\Program Files\"              },
                new { Description = "Current file path",     Path = "hello.txt"                       },
                new { Description = "Parent file path",      Path = @"..\hello.txt"                   },
                new { Description = "Parent directory path", Path = ".."                              }
            };
            PathExtractionResult[] results = inputs
                .SelectMany(
                    input => testMethods.Select(
                        method => {
                            string result;

                            try
                            {
                                string returnValue = (string) method.Invoke(null, new object[] { input.Path });

                                result = $"\"{returnValue}\"";
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                if (ex is TargetInvocationException)
                                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                                result = $"EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}";
                            }

                            return new PathExtractionResult() {
                                Description = input.Description,
                                Method = $"{method.Name}()",
                                Path = $"\"{input.Path}\"",
                                Result = result
                            };
                        }
                    )
                ).ToArray();
            const int ColumnPadding = 2;
            ResultWriter writer = new ResultWriter(Console.Out) {
                DescriptionColumnWidth = results.Max(output => output.Description.Length) + ColumnPadding,
                MethodColumnWidth = results.Max(output => output.Method.Length) + ColumnPadding,
                PathColumnWidth = results.Max(output => output.Path.Length) + ColumnPadding,
                ResultColumnWidth = results.Max(output => output.Result.Length) + ColumnPadding,
                ItemLeftPadding = " ",
                ItemRightPadding = " "
            };
            PathExtractionResult header = new PathExtractionResult() {
                Description = nameof(PathExtractionResult.Description),
                Method = nameof(PathExtractionResult.Method),
                Path = nameof(PathExtractionResult.Path),
                Result = nameof(PathExtractionResult.Result)
            };

            writer.WriteResult(header);
            writer.WriteDivider();
            foreach (IGrouping<string, PathExtractionResult> resultGroup in results.GroupBy(result => result.Description))
            {
                foreach (PathExtractionResult result in resultGroup)
                    writer.WriteResult(result);
                writer.WriteDivider();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ResultWriter
    {
        private const char DividerChar = '-';
        private const char SeparatorChar = '|';

        private TextWriter Writer { get; }

        public ResultWriter(TextWriter writer)
        {
            Writer = writer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(writer));
        }

        public int DescriptionColumnWidth { get; set; }

        public int MethodColumnWidth { get; set; }

        public int PathColumnWidth { get; set; }

        public int ResultColumnWidth { get; set; }

        public string ItemLeftPadding { get; set; }

        public string ItemRightPadding { get; set; }

        public void WriteResult(PathExtractionResult result)
        {
            WriteLine(
                $"{ItemLeftPadding}{result.Description}{ItemRightPadding}",
                $"{ItemLeftPadding}{result.Method}{ItemRightPadding}",
                $"{ItemLeftPadding}{result.Path}{ItemRightPadding}",
                $"{ItemLeftPadding}{result.Result}{ItemRightPadding}"
            );
        }

        public void WriteDivider()
        {
            WriteLine(
                new string(DividerChar, DescriptionColumnWidth),
                new string(DividerChar, MethodColumnWidth),
                new string(DividerChar, PathColumnWidth),
                new string(DividerChar, ResultColumnWidth)
            );
        }

        private void WriteLine(string description, string method, string path, string result)
        {
            Writer.Write(SeparatorChar);
            Writer.Write(description.PadRight(DescriptionColumnWidth));
            Writer.Write(SeparatorChar);
            Writer.Write(method.PadRight(MethodColumnWidth));
            Writer.Write(SeparatorChar);
            Writer.Write(path.PadRight(PathColumnWidth));
            Writer.Write(SeparatorChar);
            Writer.Write(result.PadRight(ResultColumnWidth));
            Writer.WriteLine(SeparatorChar);
        }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR** **The code in the question does not behave as many seem to expect** in some corner cases.  If you're going to write your own path manipulation code, be sure to take into consideration...

- ...how you define a "filename without extension" (is it everything before the first `.` or everything before the last `.`?)
- ...files with multiple extensions
- ...files with no extension
- ...files with a leading `.`
- ...files with a trailing `.` (probably not something you'll ever encounter on Windows, but they are [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47654779/150605))
- ...directories with an "extension" or that otherwise contain a `.`
- ...paths that end with a `\`
- ...relative paths

Not all file paths follow the usual formula of `X:\Directory\File.ext`!

Answer (score 1):

```
string filepath = "C:\\Program Files\\example.txt";
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filepath);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);
Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);

//input to the "fi" is a full path to the file from "filepath"
//This code will return the fileName from the given path

//output
//example.txt
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `FileVersionInfo` can be used on files that have no version information.  Note that `GetVersionInfo()` can only be used on paths that reference a file that already exists.  While either class can be used to get the file name, the question also asked to remove the extension, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
Namespace: using System.IO;  
 //use this to get file name dynamically 
 string filelocation = Properties.Settings.Default.Filelocation;
//use this to get file name statically 
//string filelocation = @"D:\FileDirectory\";
string[] filesname = Directory.GetFiles(filelocation); //for multiple files
```

Your path configuration in App.config file if you are going to get file name dynamically  -

```
    <userSettings>
        <ConsoleApplication13.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="Filelocation" serializeAs="String">
            <value>D:\\DeleteFileTest</value>
          </setting>
              </ConsoleApplication13.Properties.Settings>
      </userSettings>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to extract the file name without extension from a file path.  This, instead, is retrieving the immediate child files of a directory that may or may not be specified by a configuration file.  Those are not really close to the same thing.