# How can I get from a string of a directory and file name only the file name?

Tags: c#

The code:

'Files' is a `List<string>` and _indx is an `int`.

```
label22.Text = files[_indx];
```

For example in 'files' in `index[0]` I have this string:

```
D:\New folder (45)\converted.avi_Automatic\Lightning 0 Length 2 [91 - 93]\000091.bmp
```

But instead in label22.Text I want it to show me only '000091.bmp' without the rest of the directory path.

How can I do it ?

Comment: doing a `Google` Search you could have found this answer very easily http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file name from a path string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
label22.Text = Path.GetFileName(files[_indx]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `Path.GetFileName()`:

```
label22.Text = Path.GetFileName(files[_indx]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetFileName(fileName)` returns the file name without the directory.

taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
Path.GetFileName(files[_indx]);
```