# Get file name from a path string implementation in C

Tags: c

Can any one please tell me how to implement GetFileName() function in C without using string inbuilt function of C. For example
C:\Program Files\hello.txt

output : hello.txt

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Uday: Yes, but that's a built-in string function, which OP doesn't want to use.

Comment: The filename and function names are identical to what was asked and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp. Did you start with this question? Please note that you are speaking about C (not C#) which doesn't have a `GetFileName()` function nor a `string` class...

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the string looking for the last separator. If `/`, `\` and `:` are valid path separators (Windows):

```
char *getFileName(char *path) {
    char *retVal = path, p;
    for (p = path; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '/' || *p == '\\' || *p == ':') {
            retVal = p;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I'd implement to versions, one for windows one for unix.

Comment: with above code value of  retVal is coming ": Program Files hello.txt" but output required only filename means "hello.txt"

Comment: Did you put the string in your code? Remember that you need to escape `\ `.  The string will be `char path[] = "C:\\Program Files\\hello.txt"` in a C program.

Answer (score 2):

Without using built-in string functions, I assume you can't use `strlen` or `strdup`. The simplest way you can achieve that is:

```
char *fname(char *path)
{
    char *aux = path;

    /* Go to end of string, so you don't need strlen */
    while (*path++) ;

    /* Find the last occurence of \ */
    while (*path-- != '\\' && path != aux) ;

    /* It must ignore the \ */
    return (aux == path) ? path : path + 2;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646887/klas-lindb%C3%A4ck) for pointing out that the original function had no boundary check and would fail in case the provided `path` had no occurrence of `\\`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck True. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the end of the path you can copy characters from the path to another string until you find the '\' character. So after the while loop the `reverseFileName` string will be `'txt.olleH'`. The for loop reverses the `'txt.olleH'` to `'Hello.txt'`

```
char* GetFileName(char[] path)
{
      char *reverseFileName = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
      int len = strlen(path);
      int i=len-1;
      int j=0;
      while( (path[i] != '\') && (i>=0) )
      {
        reverseFileName[j] = fileName[i];
        i--;
        j++;
      }
      reverseFileName[j+1]='\0';
      int reverseLength = strlen(reverseFileName)
      char *fileName = malloc( (reverseLength+1)*sizeof(char) );
      j=0;
      for(i=reverseLength-1; i>=0; i++)
      {
        fileName[j] = reverseFileName[i];
        j++;
      }
      free(reverseFileName);
      return fileName;
 }
```

Comment: This `'\'` should be `'\\'`.

Comment: I'd say using `strlen()` us not allowed.