# How to get file name from a path in c#

Tags: c#

I want to extract the filename from a file path in C#.

For example:

```
textBox1.Text = "C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\image.png"
```

I want to copy the file name: **"image.png"** to the `textBox2`

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried to research the String api?

Comment: No i didn't. I don't know what is "string api"! Because i'm new to C#

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx. Look for Substring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file name from a path string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

Use the static `Path.GetFileName` method in `System.IO`:

```
Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\image.png"); // --> image.png
```

regarding your example:

```
textBox2.Text = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: @ilyaselouazzani don't just say it didn't work, say what happened: Was there an error or just not the text you were expecting?

Comment: Maybe it threw an error because the path was not formated properly

Answer (score 3):

System.IO.FileInfo class can help with parsing that information:

`textBox2.Text = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text).Name;`

MSDN documentation on the FileInfo class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx