# How to create folder/file that name ended with a dot in Windows?

Tags: windows

I wanna create a file that file name end with a dot in Windows.

use "mkdir a.", but i only create a folder named with "a"

And I just wonder how to write a function to create such directory, thanks

Comment: If you want to write a function, you'll need to tell us, what programming language you intend to be using.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir \\?\c:\test2.
```

this creates a folder ending with (.)
**provide drive letter**

Comment: sorry, this bad question have been redirect(duplicate), it don't have the option to mark it as solved.@@jasinth premkumar

Comment: @ jasinth premkumar it's just what i I think, but sorry, i don't have 15 reputation to do that...

Comment: No worries.
It's fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra dot and a trailing backslash:

```
mkdir a..\
```

But I highly recommend not to do so. You'll mess the directories up instantly.

Comment: I'll explain it later when I drop my phone and get my computer.

Comment: so have you gotten your computer? :P