# how to get last defined sub string from string in c#

Tags: c#

i need to get file name from string download link
for example in this link

```
~/Documents/files/Login_v4.zip
```

i need pick     **"Login_v4.zip"** string

how i can do it?

Comment: Maybe `Path.GetFileName(...)` might help you

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp) for a similar question.

You'll want to use `Path.GetFileName("~/Documents/files/Login_v4.zip")` for what you're doing.