# save the content of the text box to a variable c#

Tags: c#

I have the following method in windows form

```
private void btnSelectNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fichero = openFileDialog2.FileName.ToString();

                    txtbox_sel_fich.Text = fichero;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_sel_fich.Text) == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("file not selected", "return file selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    }
                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
                    $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
                }
            }
        }
```

and another method:

```
private void btnsubir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           string reply = "";
           string fichero = "";
           fichero = textbox_select.Text.ToString();
           // string ruta = textbox_select.Text.ToString();
           // FileInfo fich = new FileInfo(ruta);
           // fichero = fich.Name;


                if (fichero == readLastFile(fichero))
                {
                    createLog(fichero + ":this file" + fichero + " You have already been imported previously. No action is realized\n");
                     MessageBox.Show("This file" + "'" + fichero + "'" + " You have already been imported");
                }
                else
                {..
```

how can you see I have a method called "**readLastFile (fichero)**"; what it does is check in MySql in the "File" table if there is a file already imported with that name that I pass as a parameter, if it exists it does not import it to the DDBB and the program ends but if it does not exist it does the import.
The problem I have is that the file variable stores the entire path of an excel file (***c: \ ... \ helloWord.xlsx***) when what I want is that it only stores (***helloWord.xlsx***) since when I am going to do the check tells me it doesn't exist and starts loading when it shouldn't.

Some help?
I don't know if I am saving it correctly.  THANKS FOR YOUR SUPPORT

Comment: Please review this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/given-a-filesystem-path-is-there-a-shorter-way-to-extract-the-filename-without

Answer (score 0):

> I have is that the file variable stores the entire path of an excel file (c: \ ... \ helloWord.xlsx) when what I want is that it only stores (helloWord.xlsx)

Use `Path.GetFileName(...)`

[Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-5.0)  is part of the System.IO namespace