# When i try to use Regex.Replace it throws out System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, regex, replace, runtime-error, system

I have this peace of code:

```cs
string modz = Regex.Replace(mod, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "");
```

`mod` string is essentially like this:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Project\Project\bin\Debug\BALZOO.jar
```

and i want it to be `BALOO.jar` or just `BALZOO`.

Comment: Why do you think that the result of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will be a valid regex pattern? If you wanted to replace a dumb string in a dumb string, surely you would use [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0)? And if you know it's a path from which you want the file name, surely you would [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6921105/11683) `Path.GetFileName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @GSerg pointed out, a typical directory path is unlike to be a valid regex pattern, and even if it is, it is unlikely to do the replace like you would expect.
You should use the plain `string.Replace` instead.

However, there are better approaches than string replacement. Depending on what you like to do:

1. to obtain the file name only:

   ```cs
   Path.GetFileName(mod) // BALOO.jar
   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mod) // BALOO
   ```
2. to obtain the relative path to `mod` from current directory:

   ```cs
   MakeRelative(mod, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   // ...
   public static string MakeRelative(string path, string relativeTo)
   {
       return new Uri(relativeTo).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(path)).OriginalString;
   }
   ```